# setting up Postgresql 9.1 database in Django for ubuntu 11.10

Tags: python, django, postgis, ubuntu-11.10, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to configure Postgresql 9.1 in Django 1.3 . 
Note: I am doing this in Ubuntu 11.10 (oneric). Also I have postgis 1.5 installed to work with Postgresql 9.1

To my best knowledge, I have installed all the dependencies required.
I read the instructions from [this](http://haineault.com/blog/166/) blog also.

On doing the following:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I am getting this error stack.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 67, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import django.template.loaders.app_directories
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 23, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError {ProjectName}.{ModuleName}: No module named postgresql.operations
```

In local_settings.py, I have set engine name as 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'.

However after referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394331/how-to-setup-postgresql-database-in-django), I set the engine name to 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis' , I get the following error stack:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 67, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import django.template.loaders.app_directories
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 21, in <module>
    mod = import_module(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/jigish/jigbox/dev/mangrove/datawinners/datawinners/../datawinners/accountmanagement/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from datawinners.accountmanagement.post_registration_events import ngo_user_created
  File "/home/jigish/jigbox/dev/mangrove/datawinners/datawinners/../datawinners/accountmanagement/post_registration_events.py", line 3, in <module>
    from datawinners.accountmanagement.models import NGOUserProfile
  File "/home/jigish/jigbox/dev/mangrove/datawinners/datawinners/../datawinners/accountmanagement/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 51, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis' isn't an available database backend. 
Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
    'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named postgresql.operations
```

I even ensured, I have the postgis installed (Postgresql-9.1-postgis).

Where am I going wrong? What am I missing?
These are my early days working with Python, Django and Postgresql and Postgis.

Kindly point out any related helpful links on the web. I tried Googling but till now got no success.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: "To my best knowledge, I have installed all the dependencies required.". Please, elaborate on that. Have you installed psycopg2 ? Can you post the list of packages (apt and python) which you have installed with versions ? TYIA

Comment: This is already mentioned in the link mentioned in my question. Still repeating my self.

gdal-bin binutils libgeos-3.2.2 libgeos-c1 libgeos-dev libgdal1-1.8.0 libgdal1-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxml2-dev  proj

psycopg2 == 2.4.1.

Comment: What list are you talking about ? What about my questions regarding your psycopg2 installation ?

Comment: Postgresql 9.1
Postgresql-9.1-postgis
django 1.3

Comment: Did you add django.contrib.gis to INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: Can you post your settings.py ? Maybe it contains a clue ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  The common source of the error seems to be that psycopg2 isn't properly configured.

I found these posts helpful:

[Unable to syncdb in GeoDjango App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304367/unable-to-syncdb-in-geodjango-app)

[Django/Python Beginner: Error when executing python manage.py syncdb - psycopg2 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383126/django-python-beginner-error-when-executing-python-manage-py-syncdb-psycopg2)

[banging my head on setting up and running geodjango](http://postgis.17.n6.nabble.com/banging-my-head-on-setting-up-and-running-geodjango-td4914085.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should use "[django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#configure-settings-py)" as backend that's for sure; according to the [the official installation guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#ref-gis-install).

I think you can file a documentation bug there, because the documentation does not mention ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I have followed the installation guide. However, the installation guide is meant for Ubuntu 10.10 and lower Users.

I also want to let you know that the normal installation steps works fine till Ubuntu 11.04. Hence I was trying it for 11.10.