# Unable to syncdb in GeoDjango App

Tags: django, postgis, ubuntu-11.10, geodjango, postgresql-9.1

I am having a real trouble in setting up spatial database and syncing it with GeoDjango. I was able to setup the spatial database as per the geodjango documentation and create a django app but when i run

`python manage.py sqlall world`

I am getting this,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/smaranh/django-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/smaranh/django-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/smaranh/django-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/smaranh/django-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/home/smaranh/django-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/smaranh/django-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/sqlall.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.core.management.sql import sql_all
  File "/home/smaranh/django-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/home/smaranh/django-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/smaranh/django-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/smaranh/django-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/smaranh/django-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 44, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis' isn't an available database backend.
Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
    'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named psycopg2.extensions
```

I am tired and really not sure what to do? Please help

**EDIT**

Ok I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383126/django-python-beginner-error-when-executing-python-manage-py-syncdb-psycopg2) which kind of tells me what went wrong. Now when i get into the `python` from \home, and i execute `import psycopg2` it does not give me any ImportError but when i am inside the virtual env, I get the ImportError

```
(django-env)smaranh@ubuntu:~/geodjango$ python
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

Now the link guides me in how to append the path but i am not really understanding the process since I am new and i do not wish to screw it up further. So can somebody pls guide me step by step how to append the `sys.path`??

Comment: Can you post the DATABASES value on your settings.py?

Comment: `DATABASES = {
    'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'geodjango',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'smaranh',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}`

Comment: @dannyroa I think I found the answer, just edited my post, could you help me understand it and let me know how should i proceed further?

Comment: diegueus9's answer below should work. You might encounter an issue installing it on a Mac though. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944332/broken-pipe-error-when-using-pip-to-install-pycrypto-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using virtualenv you need install psycopg2 inside the environment, something like:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

but you need install some packages with apt before that:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev postgresql-server-dev-all
```

Comment: so I should first install 
`sudo apt-get install python-dev postgresql-server-dev-all`
and then install
`pip install psycopg2`

Comment: Thanks so much @diegueus9, that was really a big help