# psycopg2 nog recognized on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, psycopg2

I've installed psycopg2 on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
```

I also have python2.7 project. My version of psycopg2 is 2.4.5 which is compatible.

```
Version: 2.4.5-1build5
Provides: python2.7-psycopg2
```

But when I try to run the following command I get this error.

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

error:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 `module: No module named psycopg2`
```

My configuration in my pythonproject is right because it all worked on my local Windows. I don't know why it can't recognize or configure psycopg2.

```
>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1383153/742269

Comment: Yes, but I can't import it but it's installed