# Error loading psycopg2 module: dlopen with virtualenv django python 2.7

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Guys I stuck this problem for couple weeks already. I have tried almost every answer I could find in stack overflow.

The error is below:

```
(venv1) Caimings-MacBook-Pro:yang NLStom$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/NLStom/Desktop/hey/yang/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/NLStom/Desktop/hey/yang/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/NLStom/Desktop/hey/yang/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/NLStom/Desktop/hey/yang/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/NLStom/Desktop/hey/yang/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/NLStom/Desktop/hey/yang/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/NLStom/Desktop/hey/yang/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/NLStom/Desktop/hey/yang/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 119, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/NLStom/Desktop/hey/yang/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/NLStom/Desktop/hey/yang/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/NLStom/Desktop/hey/yang/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/NLStom/Desktop/hey/yang/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/NLStom/Desktop/hey/yang/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/NLStom/Desktop/hey/yang/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: dlopen(/Users/NLStom/Desktop/hey/yang/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQbackendPID
  Referenced from: /Users/NLStom/Desktop/hey/yang/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

I tried to using PostgreSql for my database in Django. 
Below is code in my setting

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'play',
        'USER': 'uaa',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

What have I did in PostgreSql.

```
psql (9.5.4)
Type "help" for help.

NLStom=# CREATE uaa;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "uaa"
LINE 1: CREATE uaa;
               ^
NLStom=# CREATE USER uaa;
CREATE ROLE
NLStom=# CREATE DATABASE play OWNER uaa;
CREATE DATABASE
NLStom=# \q
```

I used pip brew to install PostgreSql and used pip to install psycopg2.
I have done all of these above in virtualenv.

Also wanna mention that I install Postgres.app in my mac.

Comment: try to use port 5432.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I change the port to 5432 in setting file. Same error.... T.T

Comment: Have you tried this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383126/django-python-beginner-error-when-executing-python-manage-py-syncdb-psycopg2 . It seems that both of you had the same problem.

Comment: Hey! I solved the problem. The problem is I have a 32 bit python in my virtualenv. I fix it by create a new virtualenv...

Comment: Thank your for your link though, bro!

Answer (score 1):

Got similar issue on macOS 11.01, M1 Chip.
Solved it by deleting the venv created by pycharm and recreating it manually with `python3 -m venv /path/to/venv` and then `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`.
Following [github](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1208) issue could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error, but once I verified that psql was in my PATH and the postgres server was running in the background, I reinstalled psycopg2 with `conda install psycopg2`, and my django postgres app worked fine.