# Postgres with Django - Improperly configured. Error : ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'

Tags: python, django, postgresql

After installing and configuring postgres using an online tutorial. I am attempting to run the command

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

However I get the error

```
...
...
File "/Users/raj/Development/mywebsite/virtual/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

This is in my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '..',
        'USER':"...",
        "PASSWORD":"...",
        "HOST":"localhost",
        "PORT":"5432",
    }
}
```

Now I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383126/django-python-beginner-error-when-executing-python-manage-py-syncdb-psycopg2) thread which suggests that there might be an import issue. However If i import the package in the terminal like this it doesnt complain

```
>>> import django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2
>>>
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong here ?

Update:

The following command does not return anything

```
pip freeze | grep psycopg2
```

Also I am using Django 2.0.4

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(2, 0, 4, 'final', 0)
```

Comment: Which python/django version do you use? And what's the result from `pip freeze | grep psycopg2` ?

Comment: let me update my post

Comment: @seuling just updated my post

Comment: yes i am using virtualenv but i installed postgres using homebrew on a mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`psycopg2` is not installed in your env.

Make sure you use correct virtualenv (if use), and install psycopg2.

tye `pip install psycopg2`. (if using `pip3`, use `pip3 install psycopg2`).

ps. If you're in ubuntu, install other dependencies

`sudo apt-get install build-dep python-psycopg2`

Comment: yes that did the trick marked as the answer

Answer (score 9):

Try to install psycorpg2 using this:

`pip install psycopg2-binary`