# Psycopg[binary] and psycopg2 not working in my virtual enviornment for my django project

Tags: python, django, psycopg2

When I try to run the command
`docker-compose exec web python3  manage.py startapp accounts`

This command outputs the following complete error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/code/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 58, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 143, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 371, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 243, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 193, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 29, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module
```

In terms of research I have tried checking the psycopg documentation. The documentation told me to run command pip install psycopg2-binary but that did not work. Psycopg Documentation:
https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/install.html

Next I checked stack overflow articles. I found this article [Postgres with Django - Improperly configured. Error : ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299780/postgres-with-django-improperly-configured-error-improperlyconfigured-erro) but the solution to install psycopg2[binary] and that did not work. I also did a search on django forum but could not find answers.

In terms of troubleshooting I have tried to uninstall django and psycopg and than deleting my environment folder. After that I tried recreating my environment folder and reinstalling django and psycopg with pip.

pip list output

```
Package           Version
----------------- -------
asgiref           3.7.2
Django            5.0
pip               23.2.1
psycopg           3.1.16
psycopg-binary    3.1.16
psycopg2-binary   2.9.9
setuptools        65.5.0
sqlparse          0.4.4
typing_extensions 4.9.0
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for django_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.10.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "django-insecure-msd&ec*3%f9uohlh40ut)n%08pr-12#ewx73s@y&a*x00!4plo"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "django_project.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "django_project.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

# django_project/settings.py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "postgres",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "postgres",
        "HOST": "db",
        "PORT": 5432,
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Dockerfile

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.10.4-slim-bullseye
# Set environment variables
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code
# Install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# Copy project
COPY . .
```

Github Link
https://github.com/strikeouts27/django_for_professionals_bookstore

After implementing the changes and pushing to github I still have this error for some reason.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import psycopg as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 27, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/code/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 58, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 143, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 371, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 243, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 193, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 29, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module
```

```
when I rebuild my containers I get the following error message. 

    (project_env) andrewstribling@Andrews-MBP ch4-bookstore % docker-compose up -d --build
[+] Building 52.3s (10/11)                                                                              
 => [web internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                           0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 496B                                                               0.0s
 => [web internal] load .dockerignore                                                              0.1s
 => => transferring context: 62B                                                                   0.0s
 => [web internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10.4-slim-bullseye                 1.6s
 => [web auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [web 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.10.4-slim-bullseye@sha256:557745c5e06c874ba8  0.0s
 => [web internal] load build context                                                              7.6s
 => => transferring context: 2.63MB                                                                7.2s
 => [web 2/6] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get -y install build-essential libpq-dev     && apt-  44.9s
 => [web 3/6] WORKDIR /code                                                                        0.1s
 => [web 4/6] COPY ./requirements.txt .                                                            0.1s 
 => ERROR [web 5/6] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                                            5.4s 
------                                                                                                  
 > [web 5/6] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt:                                                       
3.934 Collecting asgiref==3.7.2                                                                         
4.427   Downloading asgiref-3.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)                                              
4.877 Collecting Django==5.0                                                                            
4.910   Downloading Django-5.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.1 MB)                                                
5.131      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━                  4.7/8.1 MB 23.4 MB/s eta 0:00:01
5.176 ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
5.176     Django==5.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/c7/61b02c0ef9e129080a8c2bffefb3cb2b9ddddece4c44dc473c1c4f0647c1/Django-5.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=3a9fd52b8dbeae335ddf4a9dfa6c6a0853a1122f1fb071a8d5eca979f73a05c8 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)):
5.176         Expected sha256 3a9fd52b8dbeae335ddf4a9dfa6c6a0853a1122f1fb071a8d5eca979f73a05c8
5.176              Got        f5cb8a6d573a7c04d96fe1a09ee42348f32fd2a3a0ae19aecd6d2ff943099f8a
5.176 
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.7.2
Django==5.0
psycopg==3.1.16
psycopg-c==3.1.16
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.9.0
```

New traceback once the python version in the docker file was edited to just python.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 136, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 574, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 89, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 63, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 316, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 292, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 274, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 275, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/dev/code/ch4-bookstore/project_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg/connection.py", line 750, in connect
    raise last_ex.with_traceback(None)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection is bad: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

settings.py

```
# django_project/settings.py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "postgres",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "postgres",
        "HOST": "db",  # set in docker-compose.yml
        "PORT": 5432,  # default postgres port
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile and docker-compose configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

##### 1. Update Dockerfile to include system dependencies for psycopg:

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.10.4-slim-bullseye

# Set environment variables
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install system dependencies for psycopg
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install build-essential libpq-dev \
    && apt-get clean

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY . .
```

For better reference on pure Python installation of psycopg, check [psycopg documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/install.html#pure-python-installation).

##### 2. Update requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.7.2
Django==5.0
psycopg==3.1.16
psycopg-c==3.1.16
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.9.0
```

---

Additionally, I noticed some potential improvements in your project structure. I'd be happy to open a pull request on your GitHub repository to suggest best practices and enhancements. Let me know if you're interested!

Comment: any help is appreciated. for some reason my error persists after making the changes.

Comment: Did you rebuild the containers ?

Comment: after attempting to rebuild the containers I have been presented a new error message regardiing hashes. what does that mean?

Comment: Try to modify the dependency installation step in Dockerfile to:  RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that psycopg2 is [properly installed](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#install-from-source) in your env.

Then change `"ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql"` to `"ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2"` in your settings.py. Your configuration should look like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "mydatabase",
        "USER": "mydatabaseuser",
        "PASSWORD": "mypassword",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": "5432",
    }
}
```

Comment: Your help is appreciated. For some reason my error persists. I have updated the github accordingly and have repasted the error message presented.

Comment: The new set of error messages you added are important and should have been included in the question from the get go. Can you share your requirements.txt? I mean the requirements.txt you tried to install from